# WordPress large query with multiple relation AND

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing posts filters for a website.

My WordPress `WP_Query` can't load a big query like this, when number of `meta_values more than 8-10`, website retuns 504 error:

```
$args = array(
'showposts' => $per_page,
'post_type' => 'casino',
'no_found_rows' => true,
'update_post_term_cache' => false,
'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
'cache_results'          => false,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'casino_categories',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $term_id
    )
),
'meta_key' => 'rating',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC',
'fields' => 'ids',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'languages',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'software',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'deposit_methods',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'withdrawal_methods',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'pending_time',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'licenses',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'withdrawal_limit',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'currenciese',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'established',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'support',
        'value' => 'val1',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
```

The query works well if I filter less than `8 meta_values.`

All of the `meta_keys` in admin panel is multiple select fields, so compare `"IN"` is not working.

Also, I tried to use ElasticPress, but elastic can't compare `"LIKE"`.

`get_posts()` and `query_posts()` didn't help.

Please help me, I'm trying to fix this for a week.

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution of my problem!

I create a new private custom `taxonomy` which called `filters`, and move my custom fields into this new tax.

Right now my `WP_Query` looks like:

```
$args = array(
  'showposts' => $per_page,
  'post_type' => 'casino',
  'no_found_rows' => true,
  'update_post_term_cache' => false,
  'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
  'cache_results'          => false,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'casino_categories',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => $term_id
    ),
    array( // "Languages" is a parent term for this IDs group
      'taxonomy' => 'filters',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => array(20, 19, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42) // Relation "OR"
    ),
    array( // "Software"
      'taxonomy' => 'filters',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => array(23, 22)
    ),
    array( // "Filter name"
      'taxonomy' => 'filters',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => array(24)
    ),
    // here another 10 terms (filters)
  ),
  'meta_key' => 'rating',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Hope this would help someone.